# Spring Boot app cannot connect to a Kafka broker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka

I am trying to build a Spring Boot application using Kafka, but I have some problems with running it. I am using Docker compose for Kafka from confluentinc and kafka is 3.4 with KRaft, instead of Zookeeper. This is docker-compose.yml:

```
    kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop
    restart: "no"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: "kafka:29092"
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms16M -Xmx48M -Xss180K -XX:-TieredCompilation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -noverify"
    depends_on:
      - "kafka"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      #      - "2181:2181"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka:29093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,CONTROLLER://kafka:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      CLUSTER_ID: 'NzA4MTg2MzAxNDU4MTFlZT'
      KAFKA_RESTART_ATTEMPTS: "10"
      KAFKA_RESTART_DELAY: "5"
```

This is Spring boot properties:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_HOST_NAME:localhost}:9092
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_HOST_NAME:localhost}:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      properties:
        acks: all
        retries: 10
        retry.backoff.ms: 1000
        max.block.ms: 20000
        delivery.timeout.ms: 30000
    admin:
      properties:
        bootstrap.servers: ${KAFKA_HOST_NAME:localhost}:9092
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_HOST_NAME:localhost}:9092
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      group-id: notification-group-id
      properties:
        acks: all
        retries: 10
        retry.backoff.ms: 1000
        max.block.ms: 20000
        delivery.timeout.ms: 30000
        spring:
          json:
            trusted:
              packages: '*'
        bootstrap.servers: ${KAFKA_HOST_NAME:localhost}:9092
```

However, I am getting This message from the Kafka container, continuously:
`[2023-06-27 05:19:53,305] INFO [MetadataLoader 1] handleSnapshot: generated a metadata delta from a snapshot at offset 767 in 12 us. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)`

And this warning/error from the Spring-Boot application side:

`INFO [,,] 45960 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 7 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 1ms, elapsed time since send: 1ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)`

I have tried to check the Kafka port from Docker, change 'KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS', etc. But both the Kafka container and the App are not connecting correctly.

One point is, Kafdrop connected via the 29092 port successfully.

Comment: The log you've posted from the controller isn't an error. It's standard logs from the Kraft process

Comment: as said by OneCricketeer, the log is not an error log

Answer (score 0):

When you use `KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` you're making the container only accept connections on that port from within the Kafka container.

You should use `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` to bind to the external interface, then the advertised listeners of localhost:9092 **and** Docker port mapping will work

Kafdrop is bound to a different listener, so isn't relevant to problem unless you containerize your Spring Boot app

Note: `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` sets all 3 clients, by default, you don't need to duplicate that config 4 more times